# when do we use "speaking of which" and "incidentally"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

According to my study, it seems that "speaking of which" and "incidentally" both introduce a related topic.

For example, "**I'm going to the gym later. Speaking of which, have you seen my workout shoes?**"

"**I'm trying to learn Spanish. Incidentally, do you know of any good language learning apps?**"

Are "speaking of which" and "incidentally" interchangeable?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, we use *speaking of which* when we *have* been speaking about a closely related topic.

*Incidentally* usually introduces a topic which is less closely related to the previous conversation.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incidentally

Comment: A point about "incidentally" is that it means that the new topic is *less important* than the main topic.  But sometimes it is used to make something *appear* less important, because the speaker doesn't want the other person to know that it is important.  "I'm having a great time at the party. Incidentally have you seen Katie here"  (subtext: I'm madly in love with Katie but I don't want anyone to know about it)